# whatsapp-web.js package does not open chat automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a whatsapp-bot using the following code

```
import pkg from 'whatsapp-web.js';
import qrCode from 'qrcode-terminal';

const { Client, LocalAuth } = pkg;

const client = new Client({
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
});

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
  // Generate and scan this code with your phone
  console.log('QR RECEIVED', qr);
  qrCode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  const content = msg.body;
  if (content == '!ping') {
    msg.reply('pong');
  }
});

client.initialize();
```

Everything works fine, but if I try to scan the code, it does scan it. But I expect it to take me to the chat but it does not. And I did not get any error.

[image]

I'm confused.

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "leadway_bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "WhatsApp bot by Leadway",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "whatsapp",
    "bot"
  ],
  "type": "module",
  "author": "AbdulAzeez",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "puppeteer": "^20.5.0",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.21.0"
  }
}
```